# Use Access Token for Authenticated Call to Twitter

Tags: php, twitter

All,
I have the following PHP code to pull the latest status from my Twitter profile. I'm achieving this with the following code:

```
$url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={$username}&count={$how_many}";
```

I created the application on my twitter page and created an access token. Do I have to use oAuth with this or can I simply update my twitter API call to utilize my access token.

The reason I'm asking on how to do this is because I've hit my API limit of 150 request per hour. I need to use an authenticated method so I can get 350 calls per hour.

Is there a simple method for this or do I need to use the Twitter oAuth wrapper to be able to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is if you don't authenticate it's always 150/hr. But make sure you close the connections to the twitter after fetching the tweets. I don't know if we can circumvent this. What I use for is to get the tweets for a user (not myself) using 
"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterusername&include_entities=1&count=5&callback=?"

where the twitterusername can be any twitter user